# Why am I getting a telegram bot ban? Telethon + aiogram

Tags: python, telethon, aiogram

I'm trying to make the possibility of authorization of the bot in the user account. I ask user to send his phone number, I call the send_code_request method, after which I ask him to send the code with spaces between characters so that the code does not become invalid. After sending the code, I see a message in the client in which I wanted to log in, about successful authorization, after which my bot is banned almost immediately and I have to create a new one. I don't understand what could be the problem.

```
#State with sending code
 if not orm.get_session(phone):
            user_client = TelegramClient(StringSession(), config.API_ID5, config.API_HASH5)
            await user_client.connect()
            await user_client.send_code_request(phone)
            text = 'Enter code with spaces between characters:'
            await message.answer(text, parse_mode='Markdown')
            await state.update_data(phone=phone)
            await ListParsing.waiting_code.set()

#State with authorization
code = message.text
    code = re.sub(r' ', '', code)
    data = await state.get_data()
    phone = data.get('phone')
    try:
        user_client = TelegramClient(StringSession(), config.API_ID5, config.API_HASH5)
        await user_client.connect()
        await user_client.sign_in(phone=phone, code=code)
        print(await user_client.get_me())
        string = await user_client.session.save()
        orm.create_session(phone, string)
```

Answer (score 0):

when the telegram sees that someone somewhere entered the code that he received, he makes it invalid.  therefore, you will not be able to make the user enter the code himself

Comment: I wrote that I ask the user to change the code so that it does not become invalid, in addition, the authorization is successful, so you are wrong